Gradient icon stroke does not work on some `path` elements
I have the following gradient definition:
 <linearGradient id='landing-page-svg-gradient' x2='1' y2='1'>
            <stop offset='0%' stopColor='#C6FFDD' />
            <stop offset='50%' stopColor='#FBD786' />
            <stop offset='100%' stopColor='#f7797d' />
          </linearGradient>

I use it as follows to make my svg icon of gradient stroke:
  <Calculator
        style={{
          stroke: 'url(#landing-page-svg-gradient) #447799',
        }}
      />

The svg result is this:
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  width="24"
  height="24"
  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
  fill="none"
  stroke="currentColor"
  stroke-width="2"
  stroke-linecap="round"
  stroke-linejoin="round"
  class="lucide lucide-calculator"
  style='stroke: url("#landing-page-svg-gradient") rgb(68, 119, 153);'
>
  <rect width="16" height="20" x="4" y="2" rx="2"></rect>
  <line x1="8" x2="16" y1="6" y2="6"></line>
  <line x1="16" x2="16" y1="14" y2="18"></line>
  <path d="M16 10h.01"></path>
  <path d="M12 10h.01"></path>
  <path d="M8 10h.01"></path>
  <path d="M12 14h.01"></path>
  <path d="M8 14h.01"></path>
  <path d="M12 18h.01"></path>
  <path d="M8 18h.01"></path>
</svg>

but the graphical result is not satisfactory as only border of calulator is gradient - how to fix that?


Sorry, gradient-fills can't be applied to horizontal or vertical lines See also "SVG Line with Gradient Stroke Won't Display if vertical or horizontal"
